# Empty Jenkins Workspace causing Jenkins build failure

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson

I edited my Jenkins job running in CI to "Delete workspace before build starts" but when I went to build the job with the new option. The build failed:

```
Started by user [8mha:AAAAmR+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQTGjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc83PyU1x6OyILUoJzMv2y+/JJUBAhiZGBgqihhk0NSjKDWzXb3RdlLBUSYGJk8GtpzUvPSSDB8G5tKinBIGIZ+sxLJE/ZzEvHT94JKizLx0a6BxUmjGOUNodHsLgAz2EgZe/dLi1CL93MzCpMQcIwDWRQFzwgAAAA==[0mmosawi
Building remotely on [8mha:AAAArx+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQTGjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc83PyU1x6OyILUoJzMv2y+/JJUBAhiZGBgqihhk0NSjKDWzXb3RdlLBUSYGJk8GtpzUvPSSDB8G5tKinBIGIZ+sxLJE/ZzEvHT94JKizLx0a6BxUmjGOUNodHsLgAypEgYV/eT83ILSktQi/ZLsVN3kxJxkXaDdpRW6RRmpOWa6FWYmuoYA2b5uWNkAAAA=[0mtke-calc-linux-rhel6-x64-1 (rhel6-java7 rhel6) in workspace /jenkins/workspace/completeness_compiler_runtime_tests
Using remote perforce client: completeness_compiler_runtime_tests-217915412
[completeness_compiler_runtime_tests] $ p4 workspace -o completeness_compiler_runtime_tests-217915412
Last build changeset: 61685
[completeness_compiler_runtime_tests] $ p4 changes -s submitted -m 1 //completeness_compiler_runtime_tests-217915412/...
[completeness_compiler_runtime_tests] $ p4 -s changes -s submitted //completeness_compiler_runtime_tests-217915412/...@61686,@61695
[completeness_compiler_runtime_tests] $ p4 describe -s 61695
[completeness_compiler_runtime_tests] $ p4 -G where //...
[completeness_compiler_runtime_tests] $ p4 -s users mosawi
[completeness_compiler_runtime_tests] $ p4 user -o mosawi
Sync'ing workspace to changelist 61695.
[completeness_compiler_runtime_tests] $ p4 -s sync //completeness_compiler_runtime_tests-217915412/...@61695
Sync complete, took 382 ms
No emails were triggered.
[completeness_compiler_runtime_tests] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson3579240812233061648.sh
+ cd /jenkins/workspace/completeness_compiler_runtime_tests/TPS/qel/automation/tools
/tmp/hudson3579240812233061648.sh: line 3: cd: /jenkins/workspace/completeness_compiler_runtime_tests/TPS/qel/automation/tools: No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Sending e-mails to: mosawi@generalatomics.com
Email was triggered for: Failure
Sending email for trigger: Failure
Sending email to: mosawi_haddadian@generalatomics.com
```

So it's not able to even find that directory. Anybody know how I can fix this? This seems like something simple but I have no idea how to fix this

Comment: Did you make sure you have mentioned the repo location

Comment: I did, I'm using perforce and the directory mappings are all correct. Keep in mind everything was working fine, the only option I added was to "Delete workspace before build starts"

Answer (score -1):

```
/tmp/hudson3579240812233061648.sh: line 3: cd: /jenkins/workspace/completeness_compiler_runtime_tests/TPS/qel/automation/tools
```

The error is in execute shell step. On line 3 in that step in your job config you are cd'ing to some directory that is relative to workspace root. Your wokrspace root is likely

```
/jenkins/workspace/completeness_compiler_runtime_tests/
```

With completeness_compiler_runtime_tests being the name of the job.
Since you've just deleted everything stored inside of /jenkins/workspace/completeness_compiler_runtime_tests/ - you can't cd to the dir mentioned in the error because it does not exist.

Regards,

C.O.